# How to use pagination in spring mvc and hibernate application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, pagination

I have developed spring MVC + MySQL and hibernate application

It handles the more than thousands of records. Here, I am using dataTable for displaying records. It working fine. But, my problem is performance issue for record loading..

When i execute the query in db server, it takes fraction of seconds to loading a thousands of records. but while i using a query via my app it takes more than 5 sec.

I think the dataTable pagination takes too much time to loading the records.. How can i resolve this type of issues. I have realize the solution is only for server side pagination.

I don't know how to make a these type of pagination like "Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next" with searching and sorting controls in server side.

So, please advice me how can i display the records from above requirements in my app.
small piece code may more helpful for my knowledge growth.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate's JPA interface in your application or native Hibernate?

Comment: Yes, I am using Hibernate's JPA

Comment: Are you aware of the `Query.setFirstResult` `Query.setMaxResults` methods? They are designed for pagination.

Comment: @VijayLeo Next question: Are you using Spring Data JPA or not?

Comment: Yes @geoand i am also using Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Spring Data JPA, check out the extremely helpful `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface. [This](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-seven-pagination/) tutorial will show you all you need to see how it used

Answer (score 0):

I have recently implemented it. Follow the steps.

whenever a url is called you send total number of data-List element
and than use jstl to sow buttons as per your need total%10 or using any algorithm.

in controller send a variable pagination that shows how much pagination

in Hibernate use

```
example:
        query.setFirstResult(1);
        query.setMaxResults(10);
```

on jsp follow this. code is bigger.

```
                         <c:if test="${not empty pendingSTT}">
                            <div class="pagination">
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function setBP(val){
                                        $("#BP").val(val);
                                    }
                                </script>
                                <form:form commandName="register" action="/veepropbeta/pendingshare" method="GET">
                                    <form:hidden path="BP" id="BP" />
                                    <ul>
                                        <c:set var="hello" value="0" />
                                        <c:if test="${not empty param['BP']}">
                                            <c:set var="hello" value="${param['BP']}" />
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${hello>0}">
                                            <li><a href=""><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="return setBP(this.value-1);" value="${hello}">Prev</button></a></li>
                                        </c:if> 
                                        <c:if test="${not empty param['BP']}">
                                            <c:set var="hello" value="${param['BP']}" />
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:forEach begin="${hello}" end="${pagination-1}" var="limit" varStatus="status" >
                                        <c:if test="${status.count<=10}" >
                                            <li><a href=""> <button class="btn btn-default" style="float: left;" onclick="return setBP(this.value-1);" value="${limit+1}">${limit+1}</button></a></li>
                                            <c:set var="last" value="${status.count}" />
                                        </c:if>
                                        <c:if test="${status.count>10}" >
                                            <c:set var="ending" value="true" />
                                        </c:if>
                                        </c:forEach>
                                        <c:if test="${ending.equals('true')}">
                                                <li><a href=""><button class="btn btn-default" onclick="return setBP(this.value-1);" value="${last+1}">Next</button></a></li>
                                        </c:if>                                                     
                                    </ul>
                                </form:form>
                            </div>
                    </c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, I am using Smart GWT in my project ,which doesn't have pagination feature.
So, only option left for me was to use pagination on the server side.
I changed my service, and made it take 4 parameters `start`,`end`,`sort-field`,`sort-direction`.
The service would return from the database `start` to `end` number of records which will be grouped by `sort-field`(one of the column of your dataTable) and `sort-direction` is either `ASC` or `DESC`.
This way user can choose the number of records he/she wants to see per page(which can be predefine values in a drop down), and you can retrieve from service those number of records(by change `start` and `end`, and calling the service). You wouldn't have to face the problem of getting thousands of records in one go.